# Use route parameters in Angular 4 with ID is String

Tags: node.js, angular

How to use route parameters with ID is String?

```html
{path: 'param/:id', component: MyComponent}
```

```html
let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

Any idea

> Blockquote

Comment: what is issue? you want get id from url? you want navigate with id?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: yes, i want navigate with id. But in angular type of ID is number, i want type of ID is STRING

Comment: Your id variable should be string. Put a breakpoint in the debugger and see for yourself.

Answer (score 8):

Using the route snapshot to get the `id` query parameter as you've shown should give you a string. If you want to implicitly convert that string to a number so you can use it in a route parameter for navigation, you can prefix the variable with a `+`:

```
// (+) converts string 'id' to a number
let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

Then:

```
this.router.navigate(['/example', id]);
```

Check out this example of getting the query param in the documentation
https://angular.io/guide/router#snapshot-the-no-observable-alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In the component you can use this code to transform from string into number:

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
        let id = +params.get('id'); // This line converts id from string into num
      });
  }
```